# Como selecionar um dropdown carregado dinamicamente com jQuery?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, formulário

Estou usando um formulário para cadastrar perguntas dinâmicas no meu sistema. Estou também gravando estes dados em uma sessão para não precisar ficar selecionando toda hora nos **dropdows** mas tem um problema:

No **submit**, no campo **Selecione uma categoria:** eu pego o ID da categoria na sessão e auto-seleciono com PHP e dou um trigger com jQuery para que, através do ID da categoria, ele consulte o banco de dados e preencha o dropdown do campo **Selecione uma ativadade:** ...

> Agora vem a treta: Quero deixar também selecionado **Atividade** porque
>   são várias perguntas para mesma Categoria e Atividade.

No carregamento, o sistema pega a ID selecionada em **Categoria** e faz a consulta em **Atividade**. O que eu tenho até agora são dois ID's em uma session (PHP) e o código jQuery abaixo:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    var param = $("#categoriaCad option:selected").val();

    $.ajax({
        url: CAMINHO_JAVASCRIPTI+"/usuarios/ajaxsubcat",
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "json",
        data: {param: param},
        success: function(data){

            $('#cadSubcategoria').find('option').remove().end().append('<option value="">Selecione uma categoria ...</option>');

            $.each(data, function(chave, valor) {

                $('#cadSubcategoria').append($('<option>').attr('value', valor.id).text(valor.atividade));
            });

        }

    });

});
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 1):

Do lado do PHP quando você fizer a requisição para pegar a lista de atividades, você pode fazer a verificação para saber qual a atividade que está na sua sessão, adicionar um parâmetro a essa lista, por exemplo atual = true e quando a sua requisição chegar do lado do javascript você pode verificar se atual é igual a true e adicionar o atributo "selected".